# JInput with parameter 'method' as <data-source> results in 'Fatal error: Call to a member function getString() on a non-object'

Tags: php, post, get, joomla3.0

I'm quite new to Joomla! (and PHP in general) and trying to learn by developing a website on my local Joomla!-Installation.
I'm using WAMP-Server with PHP 5.5.12, Apache 2.4.9 and Joomla! 3.6.4.

Now I like to retrieve data from both `$_POST` and `$_GET`. Both are equaly insecure so it is only logical to retrieve and treat them together.

According to this article https://docs.joomla.org/Secure_coding_guidelines#Secure_strings i should be able to do it like this:

```
$string = JFactory::getApplication()->input->method->getString( 'myText', '' );
```

It's not working, complaining that `'method'` is a non-object. ('Fatal error: Call to a member function getString() on a non-object')

All other data-source's from that same list (e.g. `'get'`, `'post'`, `'cookie'`, `'request'`, etc.) do not produce any error and seem to work flawless.

Unfortunately I need to retrieve data from either $_POST or $_GET (or both, but without $_COOKIE) wich is exactly what data-source=`'method'` is supposed to do.

Of course I can use `'post'` and `'get'` sequentially but that seems stupid to me if there is an option wich could do it directly (less overhead? and slimmer code).
Than I maybe have to address priority, but let's leave that aside for now.

At https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput the only Super-Global-'s mentioned are `'get'`, `'post'` and `'server'`. Not a word about the other sources that obviously
exist (no error occurring) or wich of the named sources is used as default.

My search has gone in circles for a while now and i can't find more related informations (targeting **Joomla!** or **`JInput`**, not `PHP`).
If I'm missing something fundamental here, feel free to tell me.

With this said my **questions** are now:

**Is there any setting (or update) i have to make to get the `'method'`-data-source working?**

**Is there another value (!=`'method'`) for data-source in `JInput` that can be used to directly retrieve data from exactly either `$_POST` 
or `$_GET` or do I need to sequentially call `'post'` and `'get'` to accomplish this** (maybe `'method'` was renamed due to a conflict in names)**?**

Thanks for your time reading (and maybe answering).

Comment: If you're new to PHP, why start with a framework? A non-object is likely a static function and should be called with `::` instead of `->`. PHP basics if you know what your doing.

Comment: @Xorifelse   I'm certainly still missing basics, but I'm quite sure it's not a static function. I suspect that it just dosn't exist and the documentation is outdated or just wrong. - btw. :: instead of -> results in a syntax error, unexpected '::'

Comment: Just FYI, I dont know anything about Joomla, but the error message states `getString` is not available in class `$v = JFactory::getApplication()->input->method`. I suggest a little debug, `print_r($v)` to see what *is* availble or what go's wrong.

Comment: @Xorifelse  `print_r($v)` after `$v = JFactory::getApplication()->input->method` obviously nerver get's executed. Without `->method` in the end it outputs the value inside `$_POST`. As does any of the other values for the data-source. The value `method` just is'nt supported (I think)

Comment: sorry, forgot to change variable - it outputs an big JInput Object:`JInput Object ( [options:protected] => Array ( ) [filter:protected] => JFilterInput Object ( [stripUSC] => 0 [tagsArray] => Array ( ) [attrArray] =>` etc.

Comment: I was just about to comment, that doesn't seem logical xD. Anyways, that big array should show you what methods or functions are available with `print_r(get_class_methods($v))` (sorry) for the edit

Comment: `print_r(get_class_methods(JFactory::getApplication()->input))` results in output : `Array ( [0] => __construct [1] => __get [2] => count [3] => get [4] => getArray [5] => set [6] => def [7] => __call [8] => getMethod [9] => serialize [10] => unserialize )` ---- `print_r(get_class_methods(JFactory::getApplication()->input->method))` get's an empty result instead

Comment: This means `method` is not an object (and you're calling it as one (->method)), perhaps `getMethod` is, https://docs.joomla.org/API17:JInput::getMethod.

Comment: @Xorifelse  that does not make sense (to me). All i know is, that in https://docs.joomla.org/Secure_coding_guidelines#Secure_strings it's said that `data-source: specifies where the variable is to be retrieved from (see below)` and there it says `method: The same as either GET or POST depending on how the request was made`. All other values in that list work flawless, except for this one called `method`. I can't see any of the other values in that output (and no `method` either, just getMethod) so these values are just keywords of some kind. Why they seem to be called as Methods I have no clue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out, thx to @Xorifelse for a push in the right direction.

The answers to my questions would be:

1) Is there any setting (or update) i have to make to get the 'method'- working?

---

One would have to add an array called `'_METHOD'` to the `$GLOBALS`-array in a way like this:

```
$GLOBALS['_METHOD'] = array_merge($_GET,$_POST);
```

Calling the `JInput` with data-source=`'method'` then would return the merged content of `$_GET` and `$_POST`, with `$_POST` overwriting
values in `$_GET` if they have the same key.

---

2) Is there another value (!=`'method'`) for data-source in `JInput` that can be used...?

Every existing array inside the `$GLOBALS`-array (who's name starts with an underscore ('_') character and consists of uppercase characters only) can be used by calling the `JInput` with data-source beeing the name of that array (without the leading underscore).

If one has newly created and/or filled that array prior to the call by `JInput` doesn't matter. So using a name like _GETANDPOST instead of
_METHOD in the first question would describe its purpose mutch better.

---

**BUT....**

messing around with `$GLOBALS` is commonly considered ***bad practice!!***

---

For everyone wondering how these values for the data-source in `JInput` work and why they seemingly could be called like a method
even they aren't methods:

the answer is to be found in **'magic methods'** and **'property overloading'**.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members